# How can I trick an app into thinking my processor is more advanced than it really is?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina

So the reason behind this is because I need to start using Zoom. Using the virtual background tool, users with powerful enough processors can upload photos and videos to be displayed behind them. The only issue is that my laptop isn't powerful enough to be able to support a video virtual background.

Of course, this isn't a real issue, but it would be nice if I could have a short video of the BBC dad looping in the background. So if anyone has any way to trick the zoom.us app into thinking I have a powerful enough processor, that would be great. (The necessary processor is a 6th gen i7 intel processor or later; I have a 5th gen i7 intel processor.)

Comment: "BBD dad"? TBH, if apps need _real_ processing power, you can't trick them into believing the processor has more power than it actually has. It's like convincing the bank teller you actually have more money in your checking account the what's showing on their computer screen.

Comment: That's fair enough. But surely just one generation difference in a processor can't be that much? (It's this viral video of a BBC news reporter working from home and getting interrupted by his children)

Comment: Ah! The BBC dad with the kid rolling into the room. LOL! It could be a GPU-related issue as well. That's all I got.

Comment: There's usually a very good reason for a minimum spec. Sometimes it's that performance would be unacceptable to anyone. Other times it's that a required feature is completely missing from any earlier hardware, so simply cannot be made to run.